# How to use helper files in PyCharm

Tags: machine-learning, python

I am trying to follow along with a [project written by Mike Smales - "Sound Classification using Deep Learning"](https://medium.com/@mikesmales/sound-classification-using-deep-learning-8bc2aa1990b7).  In there, the author wrote a helper file called wavfilehelper.py:

**wavehelper.py Code**

```
import struct

class WavFileHelper():
    
    def read_file_properties(self, filename):

        wave_file = open(filename,"rb")
        
        riff = wave_file.read(12)
        fmt = wave_file.read(36)
        
        num_channels_string = fmt[10:12]
        num_channels = struct.unpack('<H', num_channels_string)[0]

        sample_rate_string = fmt[12:16]
        sample_rate = struct.unpack("<I",sample_rate_string)[0]
        
        bit_depth_string = fmt[22:24]
        bit_depth = struct.unpack("<H",bit_depth_string)[0]

        return (num_channels, sample_rate, bit_depth)
```

In his main program he calls the helper file like this:

```
from helpers.wavfilehelper import WavFileHelper

wavfilehelper = WavFileHelper()
```

However, when I run this block of code in PyCharm, it complains "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers.wavfilehelper'"...how can I get this helper file to work in the PyCharm environment?  Do I have to put the `wavehelper.py` file in a special folder to be called?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've undoubtedly solved or worked-around this issue by now, but "helpers" or "utilities" or "UDFs" that get called like this need to exist in a folder within your project that contains a file called `__init__.py`. You can read up on how to structure your Python project from sites like [this](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/). See my project as an example: `main.py` does all the hard work and refers to helpers like you've shown above in the `utils` directory. See that special file I mentioned? That's the key to being able to import successfully.

[image: Python Project Snapshot]